# split normalized string in php and put in array?

Tags: php

i wanna Split this string retrieved from database with the help of `PHP`.

String  **Rahul:12345644,Jatin:23452223,Raman:33343212**

How could i show this in below result format.

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Rahul 
            (
                [0] => 12345644
            )

        [1] => Jatin
            (
                [0] => 23452223
            )

        [2] => Raman
            (
                [0] => 33343212
            )

    )
```

I tried this with

```
$arrayData = explode(",", $data);
```

the result is

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Rahul :12345644
            [1] => Jatin :23452223               
            [2] => Raman :33343212
        )
```

and after

```
foreach($arrayData as $eachValue) {
 echo $eachValue;
}
```

Comment: You can't.... your required result isn't a valid array: an array element can't be both a string value and an array at the same time

Comment: k.. can i get another solution..

Comment: Show what you actually want, and as long as it's valid we can try to give you a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change the format so that you use equal signs and ampersands, you could use the PHP built-in function [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

eg:

```
$input = "Rahul=12345644&Jatin=23452223&Raman=33343212";
parse_str($input, $output);
print_r($output);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [Rahul] => 12345644
    [Jatin] => 23452223
    [Raman] => 33343212
)
```

That's pretty close to what you're after.

If you want to keep your existing format but still use `parse_str()`, you could use `str_replace()` or `strtr()` or similar to swap the colons and commas just for the call to `parse_str()`:

```
$input = "Rahul:12345644,Jatin:23452223,Raman:33343212";
parse_str(strtr($input,':,','=&'),$output);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
$resultArray = array();
$arrayData = explode(",", $data);
foreach($arrayData as $eachValue) {
    $resultArray[] = explode(':',$eachValue);
}
```

which is (at least) a valid array structure

```
Array ([0] => Array ([0] Rahul 
                     [1] => 12345644
                    )
       [1] => Array ([0] Jatin
                     [1] => 23452223
                    )
       [2] => Array ([0] Raman
                     [1] => 33343212
                    )
     )
```